# Angular 10 the JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32, asp.net

Tags: json, angular, asp.net-core

I am following one angular asp.net core tutorial as a beginner and having the following issue every time I post.

```
"The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32. Path: $.jobType | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 99."
```

I have tried to create a model with http content type inside my service like mentioned on the below "A", "B" and "C" comment but did'nt worked.

Here is my service;

```
  //A
  //formData: ToDoJob = new ToDoJob();

  //B
  //httpoptions = {
  //  headers: new HttpHeaders({
  //    'content-type': 'application/json'
  //  })
  //} 

  postToDoJob(formData) {
    return this.http.post(environment.apiBaseURI + '/ToDoJobs', formData);
    //C
    //return this.http.post(environment.apiBaseURI + '/ToDoJobs', JSON.stringify(formData));
  }
```

Here is my ts file;

```
  toDoJobsForms: FormArray = this.fb.array([]);
  toDoTypesArray = [];


  addToDoJobForms() {
    this.toDoJobsForms.push(this.fb.group({
      jobId: [0],
      jobName: ['', Validators.required],
      jobStartDate: ['', Validators.required],
      jobEndDate: ['', Validators.required],
      jobType: [0, Validators.min(1)]
    }));
  }

  //post new record
  recordSubmit(fg: FormGroup) {
    this.toDoJobsService.postToDoJob(fg.value)
      .subscribe(
        (res: any) => { }
      );
  }
```

Here is model;

```
        [Key]
        public int JobId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(50)")]
        public string JobName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime JobStartDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime JobEndDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int JobType { get; set; }
```

And finally my html file;

```
<div class="grid-table">
  <div class="thead">
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">Job Name</div>
      <div class="td">Job Start Date</div>
      <div class="td">Job End Date</div>
      <div class="td">Job Type</div>
      <div class="td">Actions</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tbody">
    <form class="tr" [formGroup]="fg" *ngFor="let fg of toDoJobsForms.controls" (submit)="recordSubmit(fg)">

      <div class="td">
        <input class="form-control" formControlName="jobName" />
      </div>

      <div class="td">
        <input type="date" class="form-control" formControlName="jobStartDate" />
      </div>

      <div class="td">
        <input type="date" class="form-control" formControlName="jobEndDate" />
      </div>

      <div class="td">
        <select class="form-control" formControlName="jobType">
          <option value="0">Select</option>
          <option *ngFor="let item of toDoTypesArray"  >{{item.typeName}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="td">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="fg.invalid"> <i class="far fa-save fa-lg"></i> Submit</button>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

The answer from postman;
[image]

Does anyone knows that how could I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show us the JSON that is being generated? This looks like a simple JSON parsing error (and not anything particular to Angular). The likeliest problem is that you're getting a quoted string value for JobId instead of an actual number.

Comment: I have added postman response as picture

Comment: Please create a [mcve] with the emphasis here on minimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the question with changing some part of html.
Regarding the help with these answers;

[Angular select value string parsing to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59125976/angular-select-value-string-parsing-to-integer)

Changed html;

```
  <div class="td">
        <select class="form-control" formControlName="jobType">
          <option [ngValue]="0">Select</option>

          <option *ngFor="let item of toDoTypesArray" [ngValue]="item.typeId"> {{item.typeName}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
```